# Applescript to delete iMessages from Messages app

Tags: applescript, messages

I have an Applescript that sends myself and colleagues iMessages when certain events happen. Some times hundreds of iMessages are sent in a short space of time to lots of people and the Messages app fills up pretty quick.

Is there an Applescript I can run that deletes conversations from the Messages app?

(It can be a blanket 'nuke all messages', I'm not worried about keeping the history on this particular computer.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a Folder Action to empty the ~/Library/Messages folder at intervals?

Comment: I tried this, but it leaves all the conversations in place and also keeps the most recent message. All other conversation's history however is removed.